# React Native (Expo router), no back button in screen header

Tags: react-native, next.js, expo, react-navigation

Developing crossplatform app on solito react native next and tamagui ui. Here is my problem:

App initial opens on Home tab, where we have links to dynamic route from other tab (Orders). When we straightaway going to that dynamic route - we dont have back button(back to Orders tab screen) in header. But if we open Orders first and try do it, there will be back option. I see only 2 options solve this problem: rework file structure or change the navigate method.

Here current file structure of tabs:

4 tabs - Home, New order, Orders, Profile. On orders screen we have list of orders, each order have detail screen, and on detail page we can go to edit screen.

- (tabs)

  - home
  - new-order
  - orders

    - (order)

      - edit

        - [id].tsx
      - [id].tsx
      - _layout.tsx
    - index.tsx
    - _layout.tsx
  - profile
  - _layout.tsx

Here is navigate method im using:

```
import { useRouter } from 'solito/router';

<Button
...
onPress={() => push(`/home/orders/${id}`)}
/ >
```

[visual description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTan6.png)

and to be honest, I do not fully understand how to work with react native. I will be grateful for a detailed answer :)

Comment: need to see the code for you layout and one of the screens where the back button is missing